# Website shows not secure on BSNL broadband but working fine in mobile internet

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet, broadband

I have a BSNL fiber connection on that some of the sites show not secure and doesn't open. But the same site works fine with the mobile internet.

For example the StackOverflow itself shows not secure on BSNL connection but working fine with mobile internet. I have tried resetting the router this problem is with all the devices I connect, I have tested it on 4 laptops and 3 phones.

The problem is the number of sites not opening on the broadband is increasing, Initially it was 1-2 sites that were not opening on Broadband but now 3 out of 10 site do not open.

> [image]
> [image]
> [image]

Comment: What happens when you view the certificate for these sites that show up as not secure? Seems like BSNL is doing some certificate stuff when they deliver pages. Would be best to contact BSNL directly.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 Updated question with screenshots

Comment: You should click “Certificate Information” in the last screenshot and post that. That will show actual certificate details. What is posted here in these screenshots is mostly useless as it is right now.

Answer (score 0):

Your BSNL fiber most likely run a proxy that intercept SSL traffic (Using e.g. self-signed certificate), or there could be another "man in the middle" doing the same. Basically, if you have a look at the certificate errors above, you see that is says "server certificate does not match the URL". This means that the certificate presented to your browser is issued to a different domain name than the one you are visiting.

If this is the case, BSNL is actually able to see all encrypted SSL traffic you send - in cleartext -  between your browser and the site you visit.